# Several services not starting - Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a small office / home server running Ubuntu 20. We unfortunately have regular, ongoing power outages across the country. Anyways, the UPS did not have time to recharge, and when the server came back up, it seems many service have not started (Apache, NFS, Samba, Webmin, etc.)

I am able to access the machine via SSH, but not via SFTP, SMB, or NFS.

Below are what seem to be errors listed by dmesg.
How would I trace what the issue could be? I'm hoping to avoid a full reinstall, but if I must, then hoping to not have to copy all data off / back on (I do have backups, on a mirror drive in the server, along with weekly external. But the external is still a USB 2 so is terribly slow. That and having to set up every single service again, is very time consuming, so if there is a way to fix this, then great.

DMESG:

```
[    1.246819] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.249414] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/psargs-330)
[    1.252896] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[    1.254043] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[    1.255153] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    1.256301] ata6: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.257539] ata1.00: ATA-8: WDC WD10EURX-63FH1Y0, 01.01A01, max UDMA/133
[    1.258664] ata1.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[    1.260582] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/psargs-330)
[    1.262750] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[    1.263847] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[    1.264753] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    1.265693] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/psargs-330)
[    1.267859] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[    1.269069] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[    1.270285] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    1.271625] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.272591] ata6.00: ATA-8: SAMSUNG HD253GI, 1AJ10001, max UDMA/133
[    1.272679] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD10EURX-63F 1A01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.273769] ata6.00: 488397168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[    1.275142] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[    1.276444] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.277104] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    1.279171] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.280331] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.280347] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.283603] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/psargs-330)
[    1.285532] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[    1.286870] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[    1.288206] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    1.289804] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

I have tried manually restarting service, and no luck on any. A status on each doesn't show much. Trying an apt update doesn't resolve the repository name. As with a ping, I can do IP address, but hostname doesn't work either to external sites.

apt update:

```
Err:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
```

In case this was an interrupted apt, I also tried apt dist-upgrade, which gave this error.

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0755 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

systemctl status apache2

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-03-16 14:54:45 SAST; 6h ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 1618 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Warning: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.
```

journalctl -u apache2

```
-- Reboot --
Mar 16 01:15:40 samdb-dev systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 16 01:16:17 samdb-dev systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server
```

systemctl status dovecot

```
● dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-03-16 14:54:22 SAST; 6h ago
       Docs: man:dovecot(1)
             http://wiki2.dovecot.org/
    Process: 1568 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dovecot -F (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)
   Main PID: 1568 (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)

Warning: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.
```

journalctl -u dovecot

```
-- Reboot --
Mar 16 01:15:40 samdb-dev systemd[1]: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
Mar 16 01:15:53 samdb-dev dovecot[745]: master: Dovecot v2.3.11.3 (502c39af9) starting up for imap (core dumps disabled)
Mar 16 01:15:55 samdb-dev systemd[1]: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Mar 16 08:01:25 samdb-dev auth[43140]: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 08:01:25 samdb-dev auth[43140]: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 08:01:26 samdb-dev dovecot[882]: imap-login: Login: user=<ken>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.0.94, lip=192.168.0.100, mpid=43141, TLS, session=<E3a8GKG9A8TAqABe>
Mar 16 08:01:27 samdb-dev auth[43140]: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 08:01:27 samdb-dev auth[43140]: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 08:01:27 samdb-dev dovecot[882]: imap-login: Login: user=<ken>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.0.94, lip=192.168.0.100, mpid=43142, TLS, session=<nPrMGKG9AsTAqABe>
Mar 16 08:01:42 samdb-dev auth[43140]: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 08:01:42 samdb-dev auth[43140]: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 08:01:42 samdb-dev auth[43180]: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 08:01:42 samdb-dev dovecot[882]: imap-login: Login: user=<merle>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.0.94, lip=192.168.0.100, mpid=43181, TLS, session=<3IayGaG9BcTAqABe>
Mar 16 08:01:42 samdb-dev auth[43180]: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 08:01:42 samdb-dev dovecot[882]: imap-login: Login: user=<merle>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.0.94, lip=192.168.0.100, mpid=43182, TLS, session=<s6eyGaG9BsTAqABe>
Mar 16 08:01:54 samdb-dev dovecot[882]: imap(merle)<43182><s6eyGaG9BsTAqABe>: Logged out in=274 out=9658 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=1 hdr_bytes=5553 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Mar 16 08:01:54 samdb-dev dovecot[882]: imap(merle)<43181><3IayGaG9BcTAqABe>: Logged out in=62 out=616 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Mar 16 08:01:54 samdb-dev dovecot[882]: imap(ken)<43142><nPrMGKG9AsTAqABe>: Logged out in=236 out=25327 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=1 hdr_bytes=6130 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Mar 16 08:01:54 samdb-dev dovecot[882]: imap(ken)<43141><E3a8GKG9A8TAqABe>: Logged out in=119 out=958 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
```

I usually have a webserver, MySQL, PostgreSQL, webmin, dovecot IMAP running.

Any input / insight greatly appreciated.
Thank you, in advance

Comment: /var/log/syslog might have more helpful messages regarding the failure of the services to start.

Comment: Service logs can also be seen with
journalctl -u $servicename

Comment: Thank you, I shall try both!

Comment: `systemctl status SERVICE` for all the non-working services, then for more details `journalctl -u SERVICE` (where SERVICE is a placeholder for the service in question).

Comment: I edited above to add those service command outputs

Comment: Two things jump out at me:  1)  the read-only filesystem when trying to do an apt and 2) DNS isn't working.  For #1, try doing a `mount` to see what is actually mounted and it's rw/ro status.  Resolve those issues and much of your problems (particularly mysql and postgres)  _might_ go away.  For #2, you probably should address this and any other network issues before tackling the other services (SMB, NFS, apache, etc.)

Comment: Mount gives:

/dev/sdb2 on / type ext4 (ro,relatime)

tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,size=4096k,nr_inodes=1024,mode=755)

sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /srv
sdb      8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0 232.4G  0 part /

Thank you, makes a lot of sense that!!

Comment: Yep, this is almost certainly causing most of your problems: `/dev/sdb2 on / type ext4 (***ro***,relatime)`.  It's difficult though to pinpoint a cause with the information provided. It may be helpful to watch the console during boot for errors.  (with a readonly filesystem logs _may_ not be that helpful)